# Can't launch Spyder on windows 7

Tags: python-2.7, spyder

After installing Winpython on windows 7 64 bits, when I launch Spyder I face this:
ImportError: No module named encodings
Python 2.7.12 Shell works well but Spyder don't.
Do you know how to solve this problem?
I really appreciate any help you can provide

Answer (score 0):

the question is answered on github:

https://github.com/winpython/winpython/issues/397#issuecomment-249629016

https://github.com/winpython/winpython/issues/400

https://github.com/winpython/winpython/issues/401

Answer (score 0):

You Could try to uninstall that version of spyder and download Anaconda, a free package manager that comes pre-installed with spyder and should work fine, as it did for me as I have windows 7 x64